# How can i increment a jLabel address

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to figure out how to increment the number after the jLabel eg:
jLabel1 -> jLabel2, with a for statement. I don't know if this is possible but without it my idea is screwed

i have tried making the number a variable and then incrementing that, but i don't know the syntax for if i wanted to do that. I am not that fluent in code so i couldn't think of any other ways

```
 //i want to turnthis into
 jLabel1.setText("hi");
 //this
 jLabel2.setText("hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't increment a variable name, but what you might want to do is have an array of JLabels. Then you could call them like;

```
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[2];
labels[0] = jlabel1;
labels[1] = jlabel2;

labels[0].setText("hi");
labels[1].setText("hello");
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try that. I am doing a program where i want users to add to it and now i'll have to have a fat array so they can actually add to it

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean by having users add to it, to the label text? In which case are you sure you need to create a new JLabel instead of just appending to the existing label?

Comment: I am making a recipe manager, within the manager i wanted the option for the user to add a recipe. Each recipe is stored and shown through jLabels, i wanted it so i can just increment the number after the jLabel and use that as their added recipe and show the jLabel, instead of me having loads of empty hidden jLabels so when they add to it it'll rewrite and show it

Comment: Ah okay. In that case you probably want to use a List<JLabel> instead so that it doesn't have a fixed size limit